# Intellij Idea fails to recompile utilitary test classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

I'm working on a legacy project that has a weird project structure:

```
root
    com...
    test...
        src...
```

So basically we mark **root** as source and **test and src** as test sources. 
I guess because of this, every time I change a line in a test that uses a Util class from test/src, the next run fails because the Util class cannot be found anymore (I checked and the .class file still exists in the same place as before, so it seems only Idea is missing it).

```
Error:(45, 9) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable TestUtils
```

A possible solution I found would be to change the structure to a normal one, but that would mean a high chance of breaking some legacy build tool that's based on this structure.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S` ? In Module you can mark your test directory as a `Tests` and if there is any resources related to tests then you can mark it as a `Test Resources` ? And mark com as your `Sources` ? I think you can fix the issue using this.

Comment: Refer https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html

Comment: @user3145373ツ Test sources, resources and Sources are already set. What I think the problem is is that Sources contains the Test Sources folders. I'm looking for a workaround this without changing the structure.

Comment: if Test sources inside Mail source code then you can even mark it as test sources. right click on test sources and select `Mark Directory As`, you can find all this thing in last link posted by me.

Comment: That's exactly what I said we did in my question :). `So basically we mark root as source and test and src as test sources`. And as I said, the problem exists regardless of this.